# Use AWK (or SED) to get text between strings - include START string but exclude END string

Tags: parsing, awk, sed, between

I am trying to use AWK (or SED or a combination of both), to parse out log files that contain a spefic string "`Info:AgentSession`".
I want to INCLUDE the line that contains the **START** string of "`Info:AgentSession`", but not include the **END** string line, which would be "`[2015-`"  .

Here is a snippet of a text log file on a CentOS server:

```
[2015-03-30 12:23:10.999] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Handling Agent message for PieraC 
Request: ReceiveReady
Action: DoNotDisturb

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.000] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to PieraC 
Response: ReceiveReady
RequestId: 
Status: Ok
Message: 
IsReady: False

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.000] [49] [Info:Database] (BZ2411) (SqlTaskWorker.ProcessTasks) Attempting to run task. Thread: SqlTaskWorker-37. StartTime: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM. ConnectionTimeout: 15. ConnectionState: Open.

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.501] [111] [Info:Dialer] Sending Dialer message
Action: UsmCommand
Command: Transfer
IsTransfered: False

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.502] [111] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to MatthewW 
ActivityState: Wrapup
IsReady: False
IsSipRegistered: True

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.502] [79] [Info:Database] (BZ2411) (SqlTask.Execute) Attempting to start. Thread: SqlTaskWorker-67. 

[2015-03-30 12:23:16.207] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to PieraC 
Response: NonQuery
Status: Ok
Message: Query sent successfully

[2015-03-30 12:23:16.207] [88] [Info:Database] (BZ2411) (SqlTaskWorker.ProcessTasks) Attempting to run task. Thread: SqlTaskWorker-76. 
[2015-03-30 12:23:16.207] [88] [Info:Database] (BZ2411) (SqlTask.Execute) Attempting to start. Thread: SqlTaskWorker-76. 
[2015-03-30 12:23:16.208] [88] [Info:Database] (BZ2411) (SqlNonQueryTask.ExecuteCommand) Attempting to start. Thread: SqlTaskWorker-76. 
[2015-03-30 12:23:16.268] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Handling Agent message for PieraC 
Request: CallAction
CallDisposition:
```

When I run the following command:

```
awk '/Info:AgentSession/ {flag=1;next} /\[2015-/{flag=0} flag {print}' test.log
```

I get the following output:

```
Request: ReceiveReady
Action: DoNotDisturb

Response: ReceiveReady
RequestId:
Status: Ok
Message:
IsReady: False

ActivityState: Wrapup
IsReady: False
IsSipRegistered: True

Response: NonQuery
Status: Ok
Message: Query sent successfully

Request: CallAction
CallDisposition:
```

But I would like this output, to INCLUDE the **START** string of "`Info:AgentSession`", so to actually end up looking like this (Omitting all other sections of the log that do not referece the **START** string, using the beginning of the **DATE** string "**[2015-**" as the **END** string):

```
[2015-03-30 12:23:10.999] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Handling Agent message for PieraC 
Request: ReceiveReady
Action: DoNotDisturb

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.000] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to PieraC 
Response: ReceiveReady
RequestId: 
Status: Ok
Message: 
IsReady: False

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.502] [111] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to MatthewW 
ActivityState: Wrapup
IsReady: False
IsSipRegistered: True


[2015-03-30 12:23:16.207] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to PieraC 
Response: NonQuery
Status: Ok
Message: Query sent successfully

[2015-03-30 12:23:16.268] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Handling Agent message for PieraC 
Request: CallAction
CallDisposition:
```

Is this possible to do with a simple AWK or SED command?

Comment: Add a `print` command to the first block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^[[]/{f=0} /Info:AgentSession/{f=1} f' file
```

#### How it works

`awk` loops through each line of input.  For each line, the program decides whether to set the variable `f` to true (1) or false (0).  If `f` is true, the line is printed.

- `/^[[]/{f=0}`

  Anytime a line begins with `[`, `f` is set to false.
- `/Info:AgentSession/{f=1}`

  If the line contains the string `Info:AgentSession`, then the previous command is overridden and `f` is set to true.
- `f`

  If `f` is true, then `awk` prints the line.

  The above is shorthand for `f{print $0}` where, in awk, `$0` means the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/Info:AgentSession/{:a;p;n;/^$/!ba;p}' input.file
```

The command searches for a line containing the pattern `/Info:AgentSession/`. If such a line appears, the following block between the curly braces `{}` get's executed. In that block, we define a start label for the loop call it simply `:a`. Then we print the current line `p`, get the next line from input `n` and check if it is empty `/^$/`. If line is not empty `!` we step back to start of the loop `ba`. Otherwise we print that empty line as the record separator and start again searching for `/Info:AgentSession/` on the next line of input.

Output of other lines is suppressed using the `-n` command line option.

*Output:*

```
[2015-03-30 12:23:10.999] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Handling Agent message for PieraC 
Request: ReceiveReady
Action: DoNotDisturb
[2015-03-30 12:23:11.000] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to PieraC 
Response: ReceiveReady
RequestId: 
Status: Ok
Message: 
IsReady: False

[2015-03-30 12:23:11.502] [111] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to MatthewW 
ActivityState: Wrapup
IsReady: False
IsSipRegistered: True

[2015-03-30 12:23:16.207] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to PieraC 
Response: NonQuery
Status: Ok
Message: Query sent successfully

[2015-03-30 12:23:16.268] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Handling Agent message for PieraC 
Request: CallAction
CallDisposition:
```

---

An alternative would be to use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F'\n' '$1 ~ /Info:AgentSession/' RS='\n\n' ORS='\n\n' input.file
```

I define the input and output separator as a sequence of two newlines. The field separator is a single newline. If the first field of our record contains the pattern `Info:AgentSession` we print the whole record.

---

Btw, the `sed` command above can be also written without the `-n` option:

```
sed '/Info:AgentSession/{:a;n;/^$/!ba;p};d' input.file
```

In this case we are searching for a line containing `/Info:AgentSession/` and execute the following block between the curly braces if such a line was found. We define a label `:a`, print the current line and get the next line from input `n`. As long as non empty lines will follow `/^$/!` we step back to the start of the loop `ba`, otherwise we print that empty line as the record separator `p`. All other lines gets deleted `d`.

Comment: Thank @hek2mgl.  I tried this, but I only get the output of the 1st line, and not all the lines needed in between expressions.
So for example, I only get a line that looks like:

`[2015-03-30 12:23:16.207] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Sending agent message to PieraC
[2015-03-30 12:23:16.268] [124] [Info:AgentSession] Handling Agent message for PieraC`

Without any of the section below each line.

Comment: Yeah, there was a minor error. (I replaced `N` by `n`). It should work now.

Comment: Yup!  this now also works for me as well, Thanks again hek2mgl!

Comment: @ChrisCharles Also check the `awk` alternative which I've added. It is more intuitive `awk` processing since it defines the blocks simply as records.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/Info:AgentSession/,/^$/p' file
```